# USB drives recogniesd in lsusb but not fdisk

Tags: usb, mount

I have recently updated my desktop PC to Ubuntu 18.04 and can no longer use USB drives. These drives do however work in my laptop which also has Ubuntu 18.04. I can use my keyboard and mouse in the USB ports, but no USB drives work even though they all work in other computers. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to get my USB drives to work?

The drives do show up in `lsusb`:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0781:5590 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 010: ID 045e:0752 Microsoft Corp. Wired Keyboard 400
Bus 004 Device 009: ID 045e:0736 Microsoft Corp. Sidewinder X5 Mouse
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But don't show up with `fdisk -l`

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop0: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop1: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop2: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop3: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop4: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/loop5: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Permission denied
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Permission denied
```

The output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb`

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1f6b6039

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 1953521663 1953519616 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
chris@chris-pc:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1f6b6039

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 1953521663 1953519616 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

The output of `dmesg` | tail with USB unplugged is:

```
[ 1306.042750] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 1306.042754] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 4C530001130215107264
[ 1425.048893] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 2197.707699] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 2197.864832] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5590
[ 2197.864839] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2197.864843] usb 2-3: Product: Ultra
[ 2197.864847] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 2197.864850] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 4C530001130215107264
[ 2270.725891] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 7
```

And then reconnected:

```
[ 2197.864843] usb 2-3: Product: Ultra
[ 2197.864847] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 2197.864850] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 4C530001130215107264
[ 2270.725891] usb 2-3: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 2303.532514] usb 2-3: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 2303.689664] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5590
[ 2303.689671] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2303.689675] usb 2-3: Product: Ultra
[ 2303.689678] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: SanDisk
[ 2303.689682] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 4C530001130215107264
```

lsblk | grep -v loop

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 931.5G  0 part /media/chris/Media Drive
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   100M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0 518.7G  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0     1K  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0   9.3G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sdb6   8:22   0    28G  0 part /
└─sdb7   8:23   0 375.5G  0 part /home
```

Comment: **sudo** `fdisk -l`.

Comment: as @AlexP said, you **must** use `sudo` with `fdisk -l` because it use kernel command and it will be very **very** dangerous if it won't need `sudo` command; did you check with the file manager if the USB device is list in `/mnt` ?

Comment: if you dont want to sudo, go for `lsblk | grep -v loop`

Comment: @AlexP @damadam thanks for the heads up with using sudo, though even if I use sudo with `fdisk -l` my device is still not found.  There is also nothing in `/mnt`. I have updated my question with the output of `lsblk | grep -v loop`

Comment: And what does `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` have to say?

Comment: @AlexP sdb is a separate internal drive and not my usb. I updated my question with the output.